# php simplexml generating error with Count(); function

Tags: php, simplexml

When running my code, I get the following error:

`Call to a member function count() on a non-object generates a fatal error.`

What makes a non-object inside of this code? What causes this error in my code? The error comes from this specific line `$len=$xml->link->count();` If you have a plausible solution, please comment/answer below. If my code is not in-depth enough please let me know as well. Thank you!

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$theFile = file_get_contents('/home/thecookie12/public_html/links.xml');
$xmlDoc = <<<'EOT'
echo $theFile;
EOT;
```

The `$theFile's` variable gets the string from the `links.XML` file.
Links.xml source can be found here - http://lit.life/links.xml

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlDoc);
$seen=array();
$len=$xml->link->count();
for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){
   $key=(string) $xml->link[$i]->title;
   if (isset($seen[$key])) {
      unset($xml->link[$i]);
      $len--;
      $i--;
   }else{
      $seen[$key]=1;
   }
}

echo $xml->asXML();
```

Comment: Remove the `<<< EOT` thingy, you do not need it. Just use `$theFile`, or if you insist, you could use `$xmlDoc = $theFile;`...

Comment: Try `$xml->count()` or `$xml->link[0]->count()` instead